# Grant Access to Site/ Site Collection Usage Reports

Tags: 2007, usage-counters, permissions

I need to grant access to users from my Communications department to the Site and Site Collection Usage Reports on SharePoint 2007.

I read this article:

[Manage permissions for usage reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262840%28office.12%29.aspx)

But do not want to give Full Control Access to them... Any ideas? Workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! In 2007 onwards there is a special permission: View Usage Data  -  View reports on Web site usage.

Create a new Permission Level with this and you are good to go!